# SSH channel 3: tunnel Connection refused

Tags: ssh, proxy, iptables, tunnel

I try to use some game, Discord through my ssh tunnel.
So i created the tunnel via socks protocol with ssh:

```
sudo ssh -D 4343 -p 443 164.**.**.41 -v
```

If i use Firefox by configuring the proxy in the settings, it's work fine.
But to run any program, like Dofus i use proxychains-ng https://github.com/rofl0r/proxychains-ng

```
sudo proxychains4 -f ~/.proxychains.conf ~/games/Dofus/Dofus
```

The game start,
but in same time on the server i have the following lines:

```
debug1: Connection to port 4343 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 4343 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 4: new [dynamic-tcpip]
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 4343 for 127.0.0.1 port 4343, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34692 to 127.0.0.1 port 4343, nchannels 5
debug1: Connection to port 4343 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [dynamic-tcpip]
channel 4: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 4: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 4343 for 127.0.0.1 port 4343, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34694 to 127.0.0.1 port 4343, nchannels 5
debug1: Connection to port 4343 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 4: new [dynamic-tcpip]
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 4: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 4343 for 127.0.0.1 port 4343, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34696 to 127.0.0.1 port 4343, nchannels 5
debug1: channel 4: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 4343 for 127.0.0.1 port 4343, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34698 to 127.0.0.1 port 4343, nchannels 4
debug1: Connection to port 4343 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [dynamic-tcpip]
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 4343 for 127.0.0.1 port 4343, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34700 to 127.0.0.1 port 4343, nchannels 4
debug1: Connection to port 4343 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [dynamic-tcpip]
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 4343 for 127.0.0.1 port 4343, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34702 to 127.0.0.1 port 4343, nchannels 4
debug1: Connection to port 4343 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 4343 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 4: new [dynamic-tcpip]
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 4343 for 127.0.0.1 port 4343, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34704 to 127.0.0.1 port 4343, nchannels 5
debug1: Connection to port 4343 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [dynamic-tcpip]
channel 4: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 4: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 4343 for 127.0.0.1 port 4343, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34706 to 127.0.0.1 port 4343, nchannels 5
debug1: Connection to port 4343 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 4: new [dynamic-tcpip]
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 4343 for 127.0.0.1 port 4343, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34708 to 127.0.0.1 port 4343, nchannels 5
debug1: Connection to port 4343 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [dynamic-tcpip]
channel 4: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 4: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 4343 for 127.0.0.1 port 4343, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34710 to 127.0.0.1 port 4343, nchannels 5
debug1: Connection to port 4343 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 4: new [dynamic-tcpip]
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 4343 for 127.0.0.1 port 4343, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34712 to 127.0.0.1 port 4343, nchannels 5
debug1: Connection to port 4343 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [dynamic-tcpip]
channel 4: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 4343 for 127.0.0.1 port 4343, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34716 to 127.0.0.1 port 4343, nchannels 5
debug1: channel 4: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 4343 for 127.0.0.1 port 4343, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34714 to 127.0.0.1 port 4343, nchannels 4
debug1: Connection to port 4343 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 4343 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 4: new [dynamic-tcpip]
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 4: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 4343 for 127.0.0.1 port 4343, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34718 to 127.0.0.1 port 4343, nchannels 5
debug1: channel 4: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 4343 for 127.0.0.1 port 4343, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34720 to 127.0.0.1 port 4343, nchannels 4
debug1: Connection to port 4343 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [dynamic-tcpip]
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 4343 for 127.0.0.1 port 4343, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34722 to 127.0.0.1 port 4343, nchannels 4
debug1: Connection to port 4343 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [dynamic-tcpip]
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 4343 for 127.0.0.1 port 4343, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34724 to 127.0.0.1 port 4343, nchannels 4
debug1: Connection to port 4343 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [dynamic-tcpip]
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 4343 for 127.0.0.1 port 4343, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34726 to 127.0.0.1 port 4343, nchannels 4
debug1: Connection to port 4343 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [dynamic-tcpip]
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 4343 for 127.0.0.1 port 4343, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34728 to 127.0.0.1 port 4343, nchannels 4
debug1: Connection to port 4343 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [dynamic-tcpip]
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 4343 for 127.0.0.1 port 4343, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34730 to 127.0.0.1 port 4343, nchannels 4
debug1: Connection to port 4343 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [dynamic-tcpip]
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 4343 for 127.0.0.1 port 4343, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34732 to 127.0.0.1 port 4343, nchannels 4
debug1: Connection to port 4343 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [dynamic-tcpip]
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 4343 for 127.0.0.1 port 4343, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34734 to 127.0.0.1 port 4343, nchannels 4
debug1: Connection to port 4343 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [dynamic-tcpip]
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 4343 for 127.0.0.1 port 4343, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34736 to 127.0.0.1 port 4343, nchannels 4
debug1: Connection to port 4343 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [dynamic-tcpip]
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 4343 for 127.0.0.1 port 4343, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34738 to 127.0.0.1 port 4343, nchannels 4
debug1: Connection to port 4343 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [dynamic-tcpip]
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 4343 for 127.0.0.1 port 4343, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34740 to 127.0.0.1 port 4343, nchannels 4
debug1: Connection to port 4343 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [dynamic-tcpip]
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 4343 for 127.0.0.1 port 4343, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34742 to 127.0.0.1 port 4343, nchannels 4
debug1: Connection to port 4343 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [dynamic-tcpip]
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 4343 for 127.0.0.1 port 4343, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34744 to 127.0.0.1 port 4343, nchannels 4
debug1: Connection to port 4343 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [dynamic-tcpip]
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 4343 for 127.0.0.1 port 4343, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34746 to 127.0.0.1 port 4343, nchannels 4
debug1: Connection to port 4343 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [dynamic-tcpip]
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 4343 for 127.0.0.1 port 4343, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34748 to 127.0.0.1 port 4343, nchannels 4
debug1: Connection to port 4343 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [dynamic-tcpip]
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 4343 for 127.0.0.1 port 4343, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34750 to 127.0.0.1 port 4343, nchannels 4
debug1: Connection to port 4343 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [dynamic-tcpip]
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 4343 for 127.0.0.1 port 4343, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34752 to 127.0.0.1 port 4343, nchannels 4
debug1: Connection to port 4343 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug1: channel 3: new [dynamic-tcpip]
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
debug1: channel 3: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 4343 for 127.0.0.1 port 4343, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 34754 to 127.0.0.1 port 4343, nchannels 4
```

I checked if AllowTcpForwarding is enabled, and it is.

```
grep Forwarding /etc/ssh/sshd_config 
X11Forwarding yes
AllowTcpForwarding yes
```

I don't know what to do, i think i have to open, or forward something via iptables, but i don't know how really do. And i don't want open each port for each program.

Thanks you in advance for your answers.

Comment: It looks like the application is opening some ports on localhost, which is forwarded using your `proxychains` to the remote server, but it fails because it is not allowed.

Comment: @Jakuje and how i can allowed this on my server ?